# Suggestions of a good book (or online instruction) for MS Web Expressions 4?

Tags: software

I'm looking for a good book on MS Web Expressions 4.
I'm fairly experienced with web design (can code simple HTML in notepad (but prefer not to!) and have created CSS's.

Have been using FrontPage for years. Now finally ready to move up to a replacement. 
(And for those tempted to suggest "...just use XYZ instead", please my question asking for  "[replacement for FrontPage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/what-is-a-good-replacement-for-ms-frontpage)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Microsoft training videos](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc136535) (free) are a good start.
- Free copy of [Expression Web Step By Step is online.](http://expressionwebstepbystep.com/)