# What is a good replacement for MS Frontpage?

Tags: software

I've been using MS Frontpage 2003 to maintain our company website for *years*. Looking for a replacement that can:

- Import/convert a MS FrontPage website and "modernize it" (clean up the HTML to make it standards compliant, etc.)
- Supports (or converts) the substitutions (Include Page and Text substitutions that are done when the page is published (so they become static HTML).
- Leverages my knowledge of FrontPage

Looks like the likely contender is Web Expressions but I'm open to objective suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression Web will do what you need to do. It should be comfortable for you to use since you're familiar with the Microsoft UI paradigm. It also corrects a number of problems that the old Frontpage had.

While there are some other very good web editors available there will be a significant learning curve for them.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about learning HTML & CSS and using good ol' Notepad? When you write HTML code yourself you can keep it clean and retain complete control. There are good text editors like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) that have syntax highlighting and other features to make development easier.

Answer (score 1):

To continue the thought DisgruntledGoat started... I would also encourage you to consider getting a text editor and learning how to code. HTML and CSS are easy languages to learn, if you have an interest in that sort of thing. The pay-off in the long run for leaning the code rather than relying on an editor is huge.

My favorite text editor is EditPlus because of the way it preservers indention when you do word wrap - making code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is releasing Web Matrix for free and it is fairly good.

1. http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

You might want to try that out first and see if it meets your needs.